# what Mathematica Export Graph Format is easy to load in R?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I have a mathematica generated network  which I would like to fit into a power-law using R igraph package but i don't know which export format to use .

Many thanks.

Comment: I've never used igraph, or R, but [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25899516/4712538) indicates you can simply import an edge list as a simple 2-column tab-separated file.  For example, `temp = RandomGraph[{5, 8}];
Export["test.dat", List @@@ EdgeList[temp]]` will give such a file.

Comment: Identify which formats the R igraph package can read and then see if *Mathematica* can export any of those formats.  There are several [Mathematical Data Formats](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/MathematicalDataFormats.html) that are supported and many others in the [Importing and Exporting](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ImportingAndExporting.html) guide.

Comment: @JasonB . Thank you very much.

Comment: @Edmund.Thank you very much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update:**  [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM) now has a standards-compliant GraphML exporter. It produces files that will load in [R/igraph](http://igraph.org/r/) without problems.

```
<<IGraphM`
IGExport["mygraph.graphml", g]
```

The GraphML files produced by the built-in [`Export`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Export.html) function are not standard-compliant and will not load in many other programs.

---

I don't have experience with this, but you can still compare Mathematica format's with R/igraph's:

From http://igraph.org/r/doc/read_graph.html:

> `format`
>   Character constant giving the file format. Right now as_edgelist, pajek, graphml, gml, ncol, lgl, dimacs and graphdb are supported, the default is edgelist.

From http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/MathematicalDataFormats.html:

[image]

Not every format is fully supported.

Of the formats that Mathematica has built-in support for, I recommend using GML. As of M11.2, this seems to have the most robust implementation.

Comment: @Szabolcs.Thank you very much. Also may I please ask you whether there  is an equivalent of this  function."plf = power.law.fit(degree_dist, impelementation = "plfit") in M/Igraph?

Comment: @PureFunction No, I didn't include it because Mathematica already had ParetoDistribution and ZipfDistribution, which you can use with FindDistributionParameters or EstimatedDistribution.

Comment: @Szabolcs.Thanks you  very much.